# I am trying to pass a string into a function with a double pointer but getting an error

Tags: c, pointers

So I want to pass the double pointer of a character array, but I am getting this error:
"warning: comparison between pointer and integer
if (*(ptr_double+i) != ' ' && *(ptr_double+i+1) == ' ')"
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void word_counter(char **ptr_double, int len)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0, word = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {   
        if (*(ptr_double+i) != ' ' && *(ptr_double+i+1) == ' ')
            word = word + 1;
    }word++;
    printf("The number of words is %d\n", word + 1);
   
}
int main()
{
    int len, i;
    char sentence[100];
    char temp;
    char *ptr = sentence, **ptr_double = &ptr;
    printf("Enter a sentence\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(*ptr_double);
    puts(*ptr_double);
    len = strlen(*ptr_double);
    word_counter(ptr_double, len);
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't need to use `char** ptr_double` at all.

Comment: The name of the function: `vowel_counter(ptr_double, len);` is mis-leading.  Its seems that it should be called `word_counter` perhaps?

Comment: @ryyker Actually this is a part of bigger question and using double pointers is the requirement of the question that's why I have to use 'em

Comment: Hmm - I only get 4 warnings, each for unused variables: `count, j, i, temp`.  But the logic in the parse routine could use some work :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is `ptr_double` in the `word_counter` function supposed to represent? when you dereference `ptr_double + whatever` once, you get back a `char*`, but you need a `char` to compare with another `char`.

Comment: the expressions `*(array + index)` and `array[index]` are equivalent. But one is way more readable than the other.

Comment: In this specific code, `ptr_double` is just the address of `ptr`, which means it points to a **single pointer of chars**. `*ptr_double` will give you the value of this pointer. But `(ptr_double+i)` is past the end of `ptr_double`, I think you should be trying to add the `i` to `*ptr_double`, then dereference that to get a character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr_double` is a `char**`. That means `*ptr_double` is a `char*`.

So in `*(ptr_double+i) != ' '` you are comapring a `char*` to an `int` (the `' '`).

When using multiple level of pointers always make sure you know what you are dereferencing.

What you actually want is `*(*ptr_double+i)` or `(*ptr_double)[i]` as `*ptr_double` actually points to the string you want to index.

Comment: @Lodger, check your logic. The given syntax is correct and does access the character you want.